# Browser inconsistencies for text areas

Tags: forms, browser, textarea

When viewing my text area in FF it shows up a correct width (col=30) however in IE and Chrome it's significantly smaller. Anyway to fix this? Obviously as soon as I expand the width it looks good in IE and Chrome but is then too wide in FF!

```
input, textarea
{
border: 1px solid #D8CAB8;
display:block;
}


.submit input, .submit textarea
{
color: #000;
background: #ffa20f;
border: 2px outset #d7b9c9;
}
```

HTML

```
 <input type="image" value="submit" src="assets/images/submit_btn.png" width="85" height="26" border="0" alt="submit" name="submit">
```

Comment: try setting the width and height as a CSS property instead of as attributes.

Comment: Thanks this worked! If you add it as a proper answer I will tick it for you so others can see the result easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the width and height as a CSS property instead of as attributes. This is basically so as to allow the browser to reject the standards it follows and using the defined properties of CSS which are global.